# RXJS - Catch exception thrown by observer

Tags: exception, rxjs

I am new to rxjs and struggling with exception handling.

Taking the following code

```js
let sub = new Subject();

let observer1:Observer<String> =  {
    next : v => {
        console.log("next1-" + v);
        if(v==='fail') {
            throw new Error("fail1");
        }
    },
    error : e => console.error("error1-" + e),
    complete : () => console.log("complete1")
};
sub.subscribe(observer1);

try {
    sub.next("msg1");
    sub.next("msg2");
    sub.next("fail");
    sub.next("msg3");
} catch(e) {
    console.log("Caught:" + e);
}

console.log("That's all");
```

I understand that after the exception the Subject is basically dead and msg3 never makes it.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to catch the exception thrown in the Observer's next method.

The output I get is

```js
> next1-msg1 next1-msg2 next1-fail That's all
> /Users/peter/playground/rxjsstuff/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/hostReportError.js:9
>     setTimeout(function () { throw err; });
>                              ^
> 
> Error: fail1
>     at Object.next (/Users/peter/playground/rxjsstuff/dist/rxjs1.js:97:19)
>     at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (/Users/peter/playground/rxjsstuff/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:263:16)
>     at SafeSubscriber.next (/Users/peter/playground/rxjsstuff/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:201:22)
>     at Subscriber._next (/Users/peter/playground/rxjsstuff/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:139:26)
>     at Subscriber.next (/Users/peter/playground/rxjsstuff/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:103:18)
>     at Subject.next (/Users/peter/playground/rxjsstuff/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subject.js:63:25)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/peter/playground/rxjsstuff/dist/rxjs1.js:107:9)
>     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
>     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
```

I assume I am missing something fundamental here but I can't seem to find what.

I guess the high level question is - how to deal with errors/exceptions thrown in the Observer's next method when the Subject calls next?

All tips welcome!

Tx

Peter

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is that you can't and you shouldn't. How would an observable source know what kinds of errors could be thrown by its observers?

The long answer is that the error handling in RxJS has changed - for the better - in version 6.

If you look at the implementation of [`next`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.0/src/internal/Subject.ts#L53-L65) in `Subject` you'll see that there is no error handling:

```ts
next(value?: T) {
  if (this.closed) {
    throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
  }
  if (!this.isStopped) {
    const { observers } = this;
    const len = observers.length;
    const copy = observers.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      copy[i].next(value);
    }
  }
}
```

The subject just loops through its observers and `next` on each.

However, each observer is wrapped in a `Subscriber`. If you look at the source for `subscribe`, you'll see that a `Subscriber` is created by passing the observer to [`toSubscriber`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.0/src/internal/Observable.ts#L192).

In particular, the subscriber that's created is a [`SafeSubscriber`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.0/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L174). And that's where the error handling is.

If you look at [`next`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.0/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L208-L217) in the `SafeSubscriber`, you'll see that `__tryOrUnsub` is called:

```ts
next(value?: T): void {
  if (!this.isStopped && this._next) {
    const { _parentSubscriber } = this;
    if (!config.useDeprecatedSynchronousErrorHandling || !_parentSubscriber.syncErrorThrowable) {
      this.__tryOrUnsub(this._next, value);
    } else if (this.__tryOrSetError(_parentSubscriber, this._next, value)) {
      this.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

`__tryOrUnsub` will attempt to call the observer's `next` and if an error occurs, it will unsubscribe the observer from the source.

Any error that's caught by `__tryOrUnsub` will be reported using `hostReportError` - which throws the error asynchronously so that the call stack is not unwound. That's done so that errors that occur in one observer won't affect other observers.

If you add a second observer - that does not throw - to your example, you should see that the second observer behaves as you'd expect and receives `"msg3"`.

Ben Lesh explained these changes - and the reasons they were made - in a [recent presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCXZhe6KsxQ&t=5m0s). You might want to check it out.

Comment: Thanks for this! I was missing the part on hostReportError. Now need to get my head around how to get info from observer back to observable while processing the 'next' value in an rxjs ideomatic way.

Comment: Why would you need to inform an observable source of an error in the observer? Or, put another way, why would an observable source need to know anything about an observer? If a source needs to know more about an observer than is expressed in the observer's contract, I would say that is not at all idiomatic.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, so I guess I am doing something fundamentally wrong here. Use case is as follows. Through an API call an in memory table is updated. The table is the observable. Observers (views on the table) can register for table updates but depending on how they were constructed will not be able to accept all updates. Somehow I would like to let the caller of the API know that not all observers accepted that update. I am not sure this is the correct forum for such questions...but how would one do this properly using rxjs? Perhaps rxjs is not what I need to use here? Tx!

Comment: RxJS is a push-based library: sources push values to observers. As you've discovered, throwing an error in an observer is not a mechanism that can be used for bi-directional communication between a source and an observer. However, you could look at using the value - that's passed to the observers' `next` functions - to implement a bidirectional communication mechanism. If you're really curious, you might want look at André Staltz's [callbags](https://github.com/callbag/callbag) - which are push/pull. Whether or not they'd be useful for you, I don't know. I've not spent much time with them.

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate your valuable tips (and time).